# How do I get my program to keep running when a single promise resolves or rejects?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I want my program to resolve if everything worked and then go onto the next test using a for loop; or, if there is an error, I want it to run again. But if it hits an error six times, I want it to give up and try the next function with the loop.

What I expect:

```
index is 0 and loop is 0
index is 1 and loop is 0
index is 2 and loop is 0
index is 3 and loop is 0
index is 4 and loop is 0
index is 5 and loop is 0
5 is too many errors
[printed error]
index is 0 and loop is 7
index is 1 and loop is 7
index is 2 and loop is 7
index is 3 and loop is 7
index is 4 and loop is 7
index is 5 and loop is 7
5 is too many errors
[printed error] ..  and so on
```

What I actually get:

```
index is 0 and loop is 0
index is 1 and loop is 0
index is 2 and loop is 0
index is 3 and loop is 0
index is 4 and loop is 0
index is 5 and loop is 0
5 is too many errors
(node:29808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:29808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
```

The code:

```
const hello = async (index, i) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(`index is ${index} and loop is ${i}`)
        if(index === 5){
            reject(console.log(`${index} is too many errors`)) // this runs
        } else if (index === 6){
            resolve(console.log("I realize it won't ever resolve :) ")) 
        }
        else{
            hello(++index, i)
        }
    })
};

const loop_function = async () => {
    return new Promise (async(res, rej)=>{
        for (var i = 0; i <= 35; i += 7) {
            try{
                await hello(0, i)
            } catch(err){
                console.log("caught an error!") // this does not run
            }
        }
        res(console.log("resolved everything")) // this does not run
    })
}


const final = async () =>{
    await loop_function()
    console.log("loop_function complete") // this does not run
}


final();
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to amend:

1. purge the `new Promise()` wrappers from both functions; they are unnecessary as AsyncFunctions are guaranteed to return Promise and internally you can simply return/throw.
2. be sure to `return hello(++index, i)` in order to return the outcome of each level of the recursion to its superior levels, and eventually to the original caller at the topmost level.
3. when the `(index >= 5)` condition is met, simply throw an Error; there's no need to log as the caller's (loop_function's) `catch` block will do the logging.

So, you might end up with :

```js
const hello = async (index, i) => {
 console.log(`index is ${index} and loop is ${i}`);
 if(index >= 5) {
  throw new Error(`${index} is too many errors`);
 } else {
  return hello(++index, i);
 }
};
const loop_function = async () => {
 for (var i = 0; i <= 35; i += 7) {
  try {
   await hello(0, i);
  } catch(err) {
   console.log(err.message);
  }
 }
 console.log("resolved everything");
}
const final = async () =>{
 await loop_function();
 console.log("loop_function complete");
}
final();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your recursive `hello(++index, i)` call is ignored - you never use its result value. It might be a rejected promise (for which you then get the "unhandled rejection" warning), and worse, you never resolve the promise you are constructing. But you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) anyway!

```
async function hello(index, i) {
    console.log(`index is ${index} and loop is ${i}`)
    if (index === 5) {
        throw new Error(`${index} is too many errors`)
    } else if (index === 6) {
        return "I realize it won't ever resolve :)"
    } else {
        return hello(++index, i)
//      ^^^^^^ this is essential! Or at least `await` the returned promise
    }
}

async function loop() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 35; i += 7) {
        try {
            await hello(0, i)
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("caught an error!", err)
        }
    }
    console.log("resolved everything")
}

loop().then(() => {
    console.log("loop_function complete")
}, () => {
    console.log("unhandled error")
})
```